# Дублируются массивы mysql в php

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [prod_id] => 40 [sum_quantity] => 10 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [prod_id] => 46 [sum_quantity] => 1 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [prod_id] => 47 [sum_quantity] => 7 ) 
  [3] => Array ( [prod_id] => 48 [sum_quantity] => 4 ) ) 
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [prod_id] => 40 [sum_quantity] => 10 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [prod_id] => 46 [sum_quantity] => 1 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [prod_id] => 47 [sum_quantity] => 7 ) 
  [3] => Array ( [prod_id] => 48 [sum_quantity] => 4 ) ) 
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [prod_id] => 40 [sum_quantity] => 10 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [prod_id] => 46 [sum_quantity] => 1 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [prod_id] => 47 [sum_quantity] => 7 ) 
  [3] => Array ( [prod_id] => 48 [sum_quantity] => 4 ) )
```

Массив дублируется и array_uniq не помогает, как быть?

```
                $cid = (int)$this->customer->getId();
                $pid = (int)$product_query->row['product_id'];
                $customer_new = $this->db->query("
                   SELECT tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id AS prod_id, sum(tb01.quantity) AS sum_quantity
                   FROM oc_order_product AS tb01
                   LEFT JOIN oc_order AS tb02 ON tb01.order_id = tb02.order_id 
                   LEFT JOIN oc_customer AS tb03 ON tb02.customer_id = tb03.customer_id
                   WHERE tb03.customer_id = '{$cid}'
                   GROUP BY tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id
                ");
                $rows = $customer_new->rows;
                $ssd = array();
                foreach($rows as $index => $row){
                  $ssd[] = array(
                    'prod_id' => $row['prod_id'], 
                    'sum_quantity' => $row['sum_quantity']
                  );
                }



print_r($ssd);
```

Повторяются массивы с бд по 2-5 раз на разных стр по разному

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Как использовать это для меня?

Comment: к вашему вопросу добавьте результат вывода `var_dump($rows)`

Comment: а если через print_r вывести

Comment: между циклом формирования массива и его выводом еще что-то есть? вывод массива приведенный в начале, формируется одной командой `print_r`? как то весьма сомнительно. Больше похоже что вы там 3 раза ctrl+v нажали при вставке. Если это целиковый массив из трех повторов, то почему там `0 => ` индексы отсутствуют?

Comment: Раз вы собираете в один, проще будет юзать `fetch_all`.

Comment: $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input))); Как это в моем случае использовать? ошибку выдает у меня(

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее на вывод `print_r`: у вас не значения в массиве дублируются, а функция `print_r` **вызывается трижды**. Так что ошибка где-то в том коде, что вы не показали